# Unable to Add User

Tags: user-account, user, sparkpost, civicrm-spark

I am trying to add another user to my site. I am on Spark and with civihosting. When I click "create new account," I am redirected to a page that says "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." I've been having this issue for three days and can't figure out what the problem is. Everything else seems to be working perfectly fine.

Comment: I have mentioned this in the Spark channel on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/. I suspect the first question will be; what CMS, followed by; what Extensions are on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you were missing the "Unsupervised" rule in CiviCRM (from Contacts > Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts).

The default rule, by email, was set as "General".

I changed it back to "Unsupervised".

It's rather odd that CiviCRM allows this, I will see if we can add a check against it.

Comment: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19064   /  https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/-/issues/80

Comment: Added a simple system-check to the symbiotic monitoring extension for now: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/symbiotic/-/commit/8ba54131c23537957b5d172e581fb8a77959f85b